# Banco de dados não aparece as informações

Tags: php, mysql

Bom eu criei um banco de dados no `PhpMyAdmin` com nome **alunos** uma tabela chamada **informacoes** e coloquei os dados nela...

Daí fui adicionar ela no meu site quando adiciono aparece o código, em vez das informações da tabela...

Segue meu código abaixo:

```
< ?php
$tabela = msql_query("SELECT * FROM `informacoes`") ;
    while($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($tabela)){

    }

    $host = "localhost";
    $bd = "alunos";
    $user = "root";
    $senha = "";

    $conexao = mysql_connect ($host, $user, $senha) or die (mysq_error());
    mysql_select_db($bd, $conexao);

    echo"informacoes $alunoid<br />$nome<br />$email<br />$turno<br />$UF<br />";

? >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça a conexão primeiro e depois a pesquisa, tenta assim:

```
< ?php

$host = "localhost";
$bd = "alunos";
$user = "root";
$senha = "";

$conexao = mysql_connect ($host, $user, $senha) or die (mysq_error());
mysql_select_db($bd, $conexao);

$tabela = msql_query("SELECT * FROM informacoes") ;
    while($resultado = mysql_fetch_array($tabela)){
       echo "Informações: " . $resultado['idaluno'] . "<br/>" . resultado['nomealuno'] ."<br/>". resultado['email'] . "<br/>". resultado['turno'] . "<br/>" . resultado['uf'] . "<br/>";      
    }

? >
```